# Merge linestrings between two nodes based on condition

Tags: python, shapely, networkx

I am working with dense openstreetmap road networks and I am trying to simplify the network. To simplify it, I would like to merge all the linestrings that only intersect with one other line, as shown in the figure below; coloured lines should be merged into one (and as you can see in the example, some lines do not require a merge).

[image: Example of output]

I have tried the networkx deep first search (DFS) algorithms to identify paths between nodes with more than two intersections. But that doesn't seem to do the trick. See below some of the code I tried:

```
list_connections = {}
for node in node_three_plus.items():
    node_in = node[1]
    inb_list = []
    inb_list.append(node_in)
    for node_out in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(sg,node_in):
        if (node_out in node_three_plus.values()):
            break
        else:
            inb_list.append(node_out)
    list_connections[node[0]] = inb_list
```

when using this code, I get a lot of duplicates and it seems I cannot properly access the edges (and their data) by using these output coordinates.

Is there a (simple) way of doing this linemerge?

Perhaps with Shapely and/or Fiona?